# Function that can take different tables and operate on common columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a number of different tables, each with some common columns and some columns unique to each table. I'm using the Entity Framework to operate on these tables, and LINQ queries for filtering, sorting, etc. The code below is a highly simplified example of a situation I'm running into.

```
        var filter = "A";
        using (var dc = new MyDataEntities())
        {
            var rpt1 = dc.Table1.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(filter));
            var rpt2 = dc.Table2.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(filter));
            var rpt3 = dc.Table3.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(filter));
        }
```

If I decide I want to change the filter from StartsWith to Contains for example, I have to change it in 3 places. If I decide I want to add sorting, I have to add it in 3 places, etc. (As you can guess my actual code has this logic occurring across multiple classes, and a lot more than 3 instances.)

Is there some way to write a function that can take any table and operate on the common columns in that table? So my end result would be something like:

```
        using (var dc = new MyDataEntities())
        {
            var rpt1 = Filter(dc.Table1);
            var rpt2 = Filter(dc.Table2);
            var rpt3 = Filter(dc.Table3);
        }
```

That way I could put the logic to filter on the Name column on any of my tables into one Filter() function. Ideas?

Comment: have you considered adding interfaces to your entities, e.g. `INamedEntity { string Name {get;set; }`? Then you can write a class which holds your queries and has generic query methods, e.g. `List<TEntity> GetByName<TEntity>(string name) where TEntity : class, INamedEntity`. Or return `IQueryable` to filter further.

Comment: are rpt1, rpt2, rpt3 all the same type, same with Table1, Table2, Table3?

Comment: @dbarnes As it stands now they are different types, i.e. rpt1 would be IEnumerable<Table1>, rpt2 is IEnumerable<Table2>, etc. If funneling them into a common type enables a solution it's worth considering.

Comment: If you abstract away the common columns it is much easier, I can give an answer with both the abstracted and not abstracted and you can make the call yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me define all of the classes involved:

```
public class Table1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Table3
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

as you can tell there POCO's will be more complex but for this example it should be fine:

```
public class Example
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var t1 = new List<Table1>();
        var t2 = new List<Table2>();
        var t3 = new List<Table3>();
        var filter = "hello";
        Func<string, bool> filterFunc = (x) => x.StartsWith(filter);

        var rpt1 = t1.Where(x => filterFunc(x.Name));
        var rpt2 = t2.Where(x => filterFunc(x.Name));
        var rpt3 = t3.Where(x => filterFunc(x.Name));

    }
}
```

As you can see I've abstracted the filter out into a [function delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Now a possible better solution, depends on if this really makes sense or not, is to put all of the shared columns into a base class that all of these derive from:

```
public class TableCommon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Table1 : TableCommon
{}

public class Table2 : TableCommon
{}

public class Table3 : TableCommon
{}


public class Example
{

    public void Test2()
    {
        var t1 = new List<Table1>();
        var t2 = new List<Table2>();
        var t3 = new List<Table3>();

        var rpt1 = FilterData(t1);
        var rpt2 = FilterData(t2);
        var rpt3 = FilterData(t3);

    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FilterData<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) where T : TableCommon
    {
        var filter = "hello";
        Func<T, bool> pred = (x) => x.Name.StartsWith(filter);
        return data.Where(pred);
    }

}
```

What's nice about this is now you can hide away your filter logic, or even have the ability to pass in different filter by making the pred variable a parameter and allowing this function to be a lot more generic.

Now if you are not comfortable with this way using a base class and a Type constraint on FilterData, then you will have to use reflection, I've had to do this for other reasons, and it gets quite messy and unreadable very fast. That or maybe something like [dynamic linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) which again can be very messy.

Comment: Thorough response, much appreciated. I agree that the second solution would be better, but diving into the guts of the code generated by the Entity Framework for these tables is more than I want to bite off right now. The function delegate method will at least allow me to abstract out the logic into one place. Thanks again.